# WSL2 vhost IP address

Tags: lamp, wsl-2

I have set up WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 and use it for web development.
On WSL2 I have installed a LAMP stack.

I have set up some vhosts with apache in WSL2. So far it is working fine. But what I find annoying is that I have to set every day the new IP that I get for WSL in the Windows hosts file.

I have tried to set a static IP in Ubuntu, but I am not quite sure if it is the right way and if it is working. I have created in the `/etc/netplan` folder a file with an IP. Mainly I followed [this advice](https://danielmiessler.com/study/manually-set-ip-linux/).
I have set an IP address but I get an error when I do `sudo netplan apply`.

I have also tried [this approach](https://superuser.com/questions/1582234/make-ip-address-of-wsl2-static) and wrote a PowerShell script. But I don't know how this should set the IP.

I would be happy and grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you *really* need the IP address for your use-case?

WSL2 has a feature called localhostForwarding that should be enabled by default.  This *should* allow you to directly access services running inside the WSL2 instance simply by using `localhost` from within Windows.

With nothing else running in WSL, try the following from the shell:

```
python3 -m http.server 8088
```

And see if you can access it from your Windows browser at `localhost:8088`.

If this doesn't work, then you may have run into a WSL bug where localhostForwarding breaks when hibernating, or when Fast Startup is enabled in Windows (it is the default).  If that's the case, try running the following in PowerShell:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Then restart and try it again.

Then in your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, set your vhost names to `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That have solved it. I just have to add the '::1' in the windows /etc/hosts file.

Comment: @GunnarPolte Thanks - Good point aoubt `::1`.  I'll edit that into the answer.  Great to hear it got you in the right direction.

Comment: If the localhost forwarding stops working for some reason, see this post I've written for solutions: https://abdus.dev/posts/fixing-wsl2-localhost-access-issue/